# Listing all products that have a placeholder image

Tags: url, drupal, google-analytics, web-crawler

I'm running Drupal 8 and have an extremely large list of products in our commerce that needs some updating. Many of the products do not have an image yet, and have a default placeholder instead.

Would there be an easy way to retrieve a list of products or URL's that currently don't have an image (meaning they currently have the placeholder)? Are there modules for this? scripts? analytics? has anyone has a similar issue..?

Thank-you for all your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this, I would use the views module.
Create a view listing all your commerce products. Then add a filter criteria on the product image and use the operator 'Is empty (NULL)'. This should give you a list of the products with no product image set.